# jQuery UI drop on empty container/list not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with the jQuery UI sortable widget. I simply can't drop any item on an empty container. When the container has an item it works perfectly. 
I call the widget like this:

```
$(".apc_row--columns", this.$el).sortable({
    placeholder: 'apc_drop-placeholder-blocked',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    items: '.apc_inner_item',
    connectWith: ".apc_column--content",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    handle: '.move_handle',
    helper: "clone",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    distance: 0.5,
    stop: function(event, ui){
        that.droppedItem(ui.item, ui.item.index());
    }
});
```

Searching found out that the connected list/container needs a padding/min-height so jQuery could calculate the position correctly.

But the connected div ".apc_column--content" has a min-height and also a padding. I also tested to put an item with "display:none" on the container but that didn't help.

I just cannot get it to work (tested all browsers) and would really appreciate any help!

Thank you.

EDIT: Made a jsfiddle for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Sf5QW/1/

If you move all items from the left list to the right (or other way) you can't move any item to the empty list.

Comment: could you make a js fidddle?

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sf5QW/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sf5QW/2/)

Basically, you were setting the sortable on the wrong element.  I change it to the .apc_column--content element and now it works.  Since both lists have that class I also had to change the connectWith property to that as well.

Cheers.

```
$(".apc_column--content").sortable({
            placeholder: 'apc_drop-placeholder-blocked',
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            items: '.apc_inner_item',
            connectWith: ".apc_column--content",
            tolerance: "pointer",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            distance: 0.5,
            stop: function(event, ui){
                // that.droppedItem(ui.item, ui.item.index());
            }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I tested that a couple of times but seems that I call this in the wrong View (working with backbone) and the container 'apc_column--content' wasn't rendered then. THANKS :)

Answer (score 6):

u could add an empty invisible `<li></li>` to the empty ul to  solve this problem .  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully for the width of your ul after the ul is empty And when your ul is empty there is no width and as a result, you cannot drop li over it. You can check the width of ul by applying a border.
The solution is only applied width to your all ul and the problem will be sorted.
eg: .droptrue{width: 100%}  (.droptrue is my ul)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add these css to the `ul` element

```
padding: 5px;
background-color: #f3f3f9;
```

You need to add a padding to `ul` element