# Unable to Drop on an Empty List

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am making a simple web app. At one part I have to drag among two different lists - One of which may be empty. I am not able to drop to an empty list.

I have tried:

```
dropOnEmpty = true
dropOnEmpty = "true"
dropOnEmpty = false
dropOnEmpty = "false"
```

and tried stuff as on:

[How do I move an item to an empty list using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336285/how-do-i-move-an-item-to-an-empty-list-using-jquery)

[JQuery API](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists)

[Rollys Wordpress](http://rolleys.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/cant-get-jquery-sortable-to-drop-on-to-empty-lists/#)

[jQuery UI drop on empty container/list not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163709/jquery-ui-drop-on-empty-container-list-not-working)

Hidden `<li>` elements so that lists are not empty at all.

but nothing worked.

This is the HTML part:

```
<ul><li>Present</li></ul>
<ul id="present" class="sortable"></ul>   //First List
<ul><li>Future</li></ul>
<ul id="future" class="sortable"><li></li></ul>  //Second List
```

This is the jQuery function:

```
$("ul.sortable").sortable({
axis: 'y',
        cancel: "div.cal",
        connectWith: "ul",
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        update: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.sender === null) {
                var goalsNames = '';
                $(".sortable li").each(function() {
                    if (goalsNames === '') {
                        goalsNames = '["' + $(this).text();
                    } else {
                        goalsNames += '","' + $(this).text();
                    }
                });
                goalsNames += '"]';
                localStorage.setItem("goalsNames", goalsNames);
                var goalsDetails = localStorage.getItem("goalsDetails");
                console.log(goalsDetails);
                var goalsDetailsObj = JSON.parse(goalsDetails);
                $("#present li").each(function() {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(goalsDetailsObj[$(this).text()]));
                    console.log(goalsDetailsObj[$(this).text()].active);
                    goalsDetailsObj[$(this).text()].active = "present";
                });
                $("#future li").each(function() {
                    goalsDetailsObj[$(this).text()].active = "future";
                });
                localStorage.setItem("goalsDetails", JSON.stringify(goalsDetailsObj));
            }
        }
}).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `sortable` is a JQuery-UI feature to sort items **within** one list via drag and drop.

From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

> Enable a group of DOM elements to be sortable. Click on and drag an element to a new spot within the list

I would try to go with [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and you need to initialize a drop target via droppable.

```
<ul><li>Present</li></ul>
<ul id="present" class="firstList"></ul>   <!--First List-->
<ul><li>Future</li></ul>
<ul id="future" class="secondList"><li></li></ul>  <!--Second List-->
```

```
$('ul.firstList').draggable(/***/);
$('ul.secondList').droppable(/***/);
```

And read about the many options to be inserted at `/***/`.

**Update** 
I created a plunker for you as a start point: http://plnkr.co/RPlTgK

Comment: The `sortable` could be used with more than one list. Even the docs do show that very well: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists. Check the source

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper example for drag and drop among empty list hope this will help [Demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists)

Comment: didn't work..I have even mentioned this link on the question.