# Jquery sortable issue on empty bootstrap column

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, panel, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a punch of bootstrap panels inside of some columns. Now I'm trying to arrange this panels using jquery sortable but I can not bring it to work correctly.

see the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umnvgory/

My issue: If I drag a panel in the left hand an drop it to the right everything works great. But after that I want to be able to drag a panel from the right side back to the empty column on the left side but even the placeholder won't go to the left side.

I've set the `padding-top: 10px` property of the columns to actually leave them in the empty space.

My javascript looks like this:

```
 $("#container-wrapper").sortable({
   connectWith: ".connectedSort",
   items: "div.panel",
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   revert: true,
   placeholder: 'placeholder',
   forceHelperSize: true,
   zIndex: 9999
 }).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution by this post.
[jQuery UI drop on empty container/list not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163709/jquery-ui-drop-on-empty-container-list-not-working)

Make sure you define the `$().sortable()` on the right class and combine those with the `connectWith:` parameter of `sortable()`