# How to make jQuery sortable drop on empty column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Everything works fine but when I drop a column into another column, there is an empty column and I cannot drop anything in there anymore.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet">
          <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
          <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet">
          <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
          <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet">
          <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
          <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet">
          <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
          <div class="portlet-content"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/12/64/da/1264da4a3f18207dc22592102abae40d--frangipani-tattoo-plumeria-flowers.jpg"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".wrap").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    items: '.portlet',
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    distance: 0.5,
    dropOnEmpty: true
});

$(".portlet").resize(function() {
    $(".portlet").css("height", "auto");
});

$(".portlet").resizable().addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
    .find(".portlet-header")
    .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
    .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
    .end()
    .find(".portlet-content");
$(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
    $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});
$(".column").disableSelection();
```

Check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFPaj/110/), we start with four columns, but after dragging and dropping, we have empty columns and we cannot drop in them, while I would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle.
The problem was that you were creating the sortable widget on the wrong element.
Creating it on the .column element will make it work correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/WFPaj/124/

```
$(function () {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
        items: '.portlet',
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        distance: 0.1,
        dropOnEmpty: true
    });

    $(".portlet").resize(function() {
        $(".portlet").css("height", "auto");
    });

    $(".portlet").resizable().addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
        .find(".portlet-header")
        .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
        .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
        .find(".portlet-content");
    $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
        $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });
    $(".column").disableSelection();
})
```

CSS:

```
.column {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
    min-width: 190px;
}
```

Related Question:
[jQuery UI drop on empty container/list not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163709/jquery-ui-drop-on-empty-container-list-not-working)

Comment: I see, yet when we resize the items we loose the column count http://jsfiddle.net/WFPaj/116/ and we cannot get back to four columns even tho we resize item small

Comment: I see. The issue was that your column class did not have a fixed size.
When you remove the child element that has a fixed size, there is nothing to tell the div  to stay inflated.

http://jsfiddle.net/WFPaj/124/

I'm adding the CSS to my original post.